# Capture a photo and submit it in a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've got a webform with several fields but I would like to add one or more fields which allows users to take a photo which would appear as a thumbnail on the form.

1. User clicks the field or a button alongside it called 'Take photo'
2. The device's image capture or camera interface takes over and allows a photo to be taken
3. A thumbnail of the photo appears in the field

I get the feeling this is going to be quite complex, can it even be done in a webform?

Comment: Ah looks hopeful, thanks. I must have missed it when I searched

Answer (score 0):

you can easily find the questions on the google.
You can use Take-Photo feature with HTML5.

[Taking Photo And Upload With PHP](http://www.codepool.biz/tech-frontier/html5/take-a-photo-and-upload-it-on-mobile-phones-with-html5.html)